# How to access value passed into void tmin(void) function and then alter it?

Tags: c

I am working on an assignment. My teacher has given me this function

```
void tmin(void){
   return 2;
}
```

I need to take whatever value is passed into this function, manipulate it, and return it. Where I am stuck is the `tmin(void)` part. How do I work on the value that is passed in if it just says `void`? Is there a way to assign it to a new variable?

Comment: There has to be something wrong with your assignment. Either the assignment text has to be different or the code is wrong. If you want to cheat, use global variables and beware of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

A function `void f(void) { ... }` does not accept a anything to pass into the function, nor does it return anything. You need to change the signature of the function (return type and parameters and its types) and its body according to the task your teacher gave to you.